# Apache CXF Jetty configuration httpj:engine-factory ThrottlingFilter to return HTTP 503 on high load

Tags: apache, jetty, cxf, jax-rs, throttling

I have the following configuration of Jetty server inside my REST layer of Apache CXF JAX-RS:

```xml
<httpj:engine-factory bus="cxf">
  <!--
    you just need to specify the TLS Server configuration for the certain port
  -->
  <httpj:engine port="${port}">
    <httpj:tlsServerParameters>
      <sec:keyManagers keyPassword="${keystorePassword}">
        <sec:keyStore type="JKS"
                      password="${keystorePassword}"
                      file="${keystoreFile}"/>
        </sec:keyManagers>
        <sec:trustManagers>
          <sec:keyStore type="JKS"
                        password="${keystorePassword}"
                        file="${bookshelf.portal.http.keystoreFile}"/>
      </sec:trustManagers>
    </httpj:tlsServerParameters>

    <httpj:threadingParameters minThreads="5"
                               maxThreads="15" />

    <httpj:sessionSupport>true</httpj:sessionSupport>
  </httpj:engine>
</httpj:engine-factory>
```

I would like to configure Jetty to use ThrottlingFilter to throw HTTP 503 error upon a high load on server.

How do I do that?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?